# docker-compose need to get properties by service name , espesely ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to get the ports from the services I defined in the compose_file.yml
as i need to  to extract the ports docker generate me.
no option to inject them to docker .

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  oracleTest:
    image: ora_image
    container_name: "test1"
    ports:
     - 15211:1521

  mysqlTest:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: "test2"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 33061:3306
```

what I found is that I can get the ports by container name , this is not what I need
I can get the services with :

```
docker-compose ps --services
```

also can cat the mapped port with docker command again not what I need

```
docker port mysql8.0 | cut -d':' -f 2
```

what I need is something like this pseudo code:

```
 docker-compose -f compose_file.yml port oracleTest
```

or any think like this ... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Since `docker-compose.yml` is a regular YAML file, you can use `yq` as YAML shell parser.

> [kislyuk/yq: Command-line YAML and XML processor - jq wrapper for YAML/XML documents](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)
>
> Command-line YAML and XML processor - jq wrapper for YAML/XML documents https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/

### install yq and jq

```
pip install yq
pip install jq
```

### Parse ports from `docker-compose.yml`

```
cat docker-compose.yml | yq '.services|.[].ports' 
[
  "15211:1521"
]
[
  "33061:3306"
]
```

### Get ports of `oracleTest`

> what i need is something like this pseudo code:
>
> `docker-compose -f compose_file.yml port oracleTest`

To get ports of specific service, use:

```
cat docker-compose.yml | yq '.services.oracleTest.ports' 
[
  "15211:1521"
]
```

Comment: Thanks , but i need someting that is docker build-in

Answer (score 0):

If you want ports to be access explicitly anyway, then you might want to inject the port into `docker-compose.yml` file vie environment variables.

Say you have `.env` file (default for docker-compose to look up) as follow

```
oraclePort=15211
mysqlPort=33061
```

you can then edit your `docker-compose.yml` to accept variable as

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  oracleTest:
    image: ora_image
    container_name: "test1"
    ports:
     -$oraclePort:1521 #<-- notice the variable

  mysqlTest:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: "test2"
    restart: always
    ports:
      -$mysqlPort:3306 #<-- notice the variable
```

hope this is what you need.

Comment: no i can't this is the problem i need the The opposite to extract the ports docker generate me